# Simple API authentication scheme for SPA

Tags: rest, api, http, authentication, jwt

I'm in a search for a simple authentication scheme for SPA web application with a single REST API backend.

### Requirements are:

1. authentication against a custom credential store (should be flexible enough);
2. automatically logout user after a specified idle timeout;
3. respect best security practices.

### Current idea:

1. use HTTPS;
2. create an authentication API endpoint;
3. SPA will passes user credentials to authentication API endpoint;
4. in case of a successful authentication foregoing API endpoint responds with token (JWT, includes: user ID, optional user ID version; has expiration time set to now + allowed idle timeout);
5. SPA stores token in browsers Local Storage;
6. henceforth SPA includes token in headers of all API requests;
7. all protected API endpoints verify provided token and extract user ID from it;
8. SPA tracks expiration time of the token, when it approaches, SPA sends renewal request to authentication API endpoint (does not include credentials, only curent token);
9. authentication API endpoint handles renewal requests and responds with either new tokens or 401 status code.

### I anticipate the following benefits of this approach:

1. *simplilicy* - 2 backend components are required (authentication API endpoint and token validation/parsing utility) + 3 SPA components (login, refresh, insert token into request headers);
2. *flexibility* - token contains only identification claim, it does not restrict access control implementation in any way nor it restricts underlying authentication scheme;
3. *no sessions required* - no need to query session store, potentially it is good for performance;
4. *ability to invalidate single user token* - could be achieved by increasing (or altering) user ID version in user store.

### So the questions are:

What am I missing?
Are there any drawbacks in this scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the counter-arguments why JWT might not be the best fit for your use case:

> automatically logout user after a specified idle timeout;

Since JWT tokens are immutable you can't check how long an user has been idle (since you can't check when the last action was made)

Also there is no "good way" to revoke a token. The possible ways are:

- use short expiration time (users have to relog often)
- keep a blacklist of revoked tokens (what you basically proposed, but then your application wouldn't be stateless)
- changing the secret key (but that invalidates all existing tokens for all users)

-- they all have their cons.

> no sessions required - no need to query session store, potentially it
> is good for performance;
>
> ability to invalidate single user token -
> could be achieved by increasing (or altering) user ID version in user
> store.

It would be good for performance if your application would be stateless but doing it that way would be keeping the state in the user store.

Comment: Regarding _automatically logout user after a specified idle timeout_ - in proposed scheme it is implemented using "rolling" tokens: tokens have a relatively short life time (1 - 10 minutes), SPA has to renew them quite frequently. If SPA does not renew the token, it expires and logout occurs.

Comment: Regarding _sessions_ and _statelessness_ - having a kind of a version field in user account does not make the backend _stateful_ - it still does not keep track of sessions. But it allows the backend to act differently in various situations: for most of API endpoints it could be enough just to verify token and extract user ID; for specific API endpoints (authentication API endpoint during token renewal, for example) it would be necessary to verify token, extract user ID and compare user ID version with user store.

Comment: regarding statelessness - Stateless programming is related to the mathematical notion of a function, which when called with the same arguments, always return the same results. This is a key concept of the functional programming paradigm - thus if you keep user ID in say database and compare that to the one in token, it is not stateless. You are practically storing the state on the server.

Comment: regarding rolling tokens - that could work but security would be an issue. If someone manages to steal the access token he could keep it alive forever? Though I guess that can be worked around (ie. have maximum amount of renewals)

Comment: regarding statelessness - Even if I choose to use user name as user ID? Because in this case it's a plain JWT and it is considered stateless as far as I undesrtand.

Comment: User ID version could be represented as a number which is incremented each time the user changes passowrd, for example. This way it will not be possible to renew token if user password has changed.

Comment: you would still be keeping track of state. But if you want to use JWT for your use case, that would indeed be the best approach.